# LaTeX \cite giving a [?]

Tags: latex, tex, bibtex

in blah.tex , I have a

```
\cite{blah}
```

I have a 'blah' entry in blah.bib

I run my file with :

```
latex blah.tex && blah.tex && dvipdf blah.dvi
```

The blah.pdf results in [?]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a second `latex`:

```
latex blah.tex && latex blah.tex && dvipdf blah.dvi
------------------^
```

If you use BibTex (which you obviously do), you'll probably have to issue the command a third time (two times after applying `bibtex blah`):

```
latex blah.tex && \ # that's for preparing for bibtex
bibtex blah && \
latex blah.tex && \ # that's for resolving the crossrefs
latex blah.tex && \ # and that for putting them in the right place
dvipdf blah.dvi
```

Comment: LaTeX has all the hassle but also all the power of non-GUI applications. You pay this price for good typography, and after all, you can put together a small Bash script or Makefile for this.

Comment: Oh, I think LaTeX is wonderful. But in this specific instance I can't think of any reason why you might want to run it without resolving the references - so the double/triple pass should surely be built-in.

Comment: @Tom: You might not be using Bibtex to generate the .bbl file.  Inconvenience is Freedom!

Answer (score 3):

You could also adopt `latexmk` and not have to think about all this process anymore :)
Just do
    latexmk blah
and it will take care of compiling everything the correct number of times. It's bundled with any good TeX distribution, and you can get the manual with `texdoc latexmk`.

Comment: usage for myfile.tex (omit -pdf for dvi output) `latexmk -pdf myfile.tex` also latexmk has the -pvc option which is 'continuous preview mode' which will recompile as the source file changes (when saved). Great addition to your LaTeX toolbox!

Answer (score 1):

Latex does not look in your .bib file - it looks in your .bbl file.  Have you run bibtex on your .bib file to generate your .bbl file?  Is your 'blah' entry in your .bbl file?  If not, run bibtex again.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it for the second time, you're done. Otherwise, clear all the auxillary files bla.tex produces and recompile twice.